# Does rsync looks for modified files also

Tags: linux, rsync, backup-restoration

I have an rsync backup with me I want to restore it on a Vmware virtual machine.
The back I have is of a Guest OS which is running on LVM and where I want to restore is a guest running on Vmware.My problem is the LVM size was 100GB while the vmware guest size is just 20 Gb actually only 20Gb of the LVM was filled rest is all empty.So my cause of worry is would an rsync in this situation over write the config files in /etc which are already existing on the Vmware guest.Since I want only those files which are important for working of my application to be copied to the Linux guest OS and this includes some configurations in /etc which might not be same on the Vmware machine for example the /boot on LVM is pointing to an LVM thing where as on the Vmware machine it points to the vmdk image so the back restoration process here can mess around with what I want to achieve.If I have not made myself clear then let me know.If some one already has done this then let me know what was their experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unless you explicitly tell it not to with `--ignore-existing`. But I'd handle the files in `/etc` manually myself regardless.